# Organisation chart in latex using tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I would like to do a organisation chart with pictures, name, mobile.nr and email in each node... I tried with the tikz tree bit failed. How can i add pictures in a node? [image: Chart over the organisation] Can someone help me? Please

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please add a minimum (working) example? It would help the solvers a lot to actually start working on it.

Comment: You should probably have a look at this site for examples with tikz :
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/
and come back for specific problem when you have some.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=cyan!70!black
  ]{hyperref}

\tikzset{
basic/.style={
  draw, 
  text width=6.5cm,
  minimum height=40pt, 
  font=\sffamily,
  inner sep=0pt,
  },
}

\newcommand\mynode[7][]{
  \node[#1] (#2) 
  {\parbox{20pt}{%
      \includegraphics[height=40pt,width=20pt]{#3}}%
    \parbox{10pt}{\mbox{}}%  
    \parbox{\dimexpr6.5cm-30pt\relax}{#4\\[.4ex]#5\\\footnotesize\texttt{#6}\ \url{#7}}%
  };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=80mm},
  edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex,
  every node/.style={basic}
  ]

% root
\mynode{root}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}

% The first level
\mynode[below left= of root]{c1}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of root]{c2}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below right= of root]{c3}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}

\begin{scope}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth and 1cm]
\mynode[below = 10pt of c1, xshift=15pt]{c11}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c11]{c12}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c12]{c13}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}

\mynode[below = 10pt of c2, xshift=15pt]{c21}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c21]{c22}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c22]{c23}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c23]{c24}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}

\mynode[below = 10pt of c3, xshift=15pt]{c31}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c31]{c32}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c32]{c33}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c33]{c34}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\mynode[below = of c34]{c35}{flor}{No Body}{All and nothing}{00-123456}{anywhere@home.com}
\end{scope}

% lines from root to level 1
\draw (root.south) -- ++(0,-13pt) -| (c1.north);
\draw (root.south) -- ++(0,-13pt) -| coordinate[pos=0.05] (aux) (c3.north);
\draw (aux) -- (aux|-c2.north);

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\foreach \value in {1,2,3}
  \draw[->] ([xshift=6pt]c1.south west) |- (c1\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
  \draw[->] ([xshift=6pt]c2.south west) |- (c2\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
  \draw[->] ([xshift=6pt]c3.south west) |- (c3\value.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\mynode` has one optional argument to pass options to the internal node used and six mandatory arguments (if the image for every node is the same, the definition can be simplified):

```
\mynode[<options for the node>]{<name>}{<image file>}{<text line1>}{<text line2>}{<telephone number>}{<url>}
```